# Which activation function should be used at intermediate Layers in a Time Series Prediction Task

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a Time series prediction model using LSTM,

> Which activation function should be used at intermediate layers?
>
> Is Linear activation function is good for Final or Output Layer?

I am normalising my input data in range (0, 1) and inverse normalise after prediction.

Here is My Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(input_n, n_features),return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_features, input_n), return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_n))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()
```

Here I have used 'relu' in intermediate layers and Linear activation at my output layer.
Is this approach correct, or in the  intermediate layer I should also try with tanh and sigmoid.
What will happen if I will not use any activation function in the intermediate layer, will LSTM take care of this.
Actually LSTM already having tanh and sigmoid activation function for its internal gate calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Word of warning: this is my subjective impression which is mostly (but not completely backed) by scientific research.

I can verify that ReLU and its derivates (PReLU, Leaky ReLU, etc.) have produced the best results for me in the past.

Which of those implementations will produce the best results for you is probably best determined by trying them out, if you can afford to do so.

Comment: Here I am looking for, whether to use Relu or Sigmoid or tanh.
Anyways variations of Relu can also be tried.

Answer (score -2):

ReLU is prettymuch better for deep learning models as an activation function.This normalizes your input and output in the range of [0,1] and adds non linearity

Comment: ReLU stands for rectified linear unit, and is a type of activation function. Mathematically, it is defined as y = max(0, x). 
So output of relu is not [0,1].